# Subsetting data table by using NA's (or some other value) as endpoints for the subsets

Tags: r, data.table, subset, na

I am attempting to subset a data table by using some NA values in a column as the end points for the subsetting.  Here is some fake data to show what I mean:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(34)
somestuff <- c(NA,'sdr','utyrd','ytrd','fc',NA,NA,'09h','87h',NA,NA,NA,'0ij','5fdg','g7','h8o7hy')
someotherstuff <- sample(LETTERS,length(somestuff))

dat <- data.table(somestuff,someotherstuff)
```

I would like to subset 'dat' to the following 3 subsets (dat1, dat2, dat3 below).  Basically to remove the rows with NA but to also leverage some of those NA values in the first column as the non-inclusive endpoints for the subsetting. In other words, the groups for subsetting are separated by single or multiple cells of NAs in a column.

```
dat1 <- dat[2:5]
dat2 <- dat[8:9]
dat3 <- dat[13:16]
```

The actual data I will be using will have several subsets and usually multiple consecutive NA values in a column and when I pull this data each week it will have these NA's in different places.  I wanted to see if anyone knew of an efficient way to subset based on using a common element (like NA) or string within a column to specify the subsetting endpoints.  I'm not wed to a data.table solution though I tend to use these most.  I've been trying split() such as this:

```
split(dat,by=is.na(dat$somestuff))
```

as well as appending a counter to rows without the NA but it doesn't seem to be coming together.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a grouping variable with `rleid` and then `split` into a `list` of `data.table`s

```
dt <- dat[,  grp := rleid(is.na(somestuff))][!is.na(somestuff), .SD]          
unname(split(dt, by = "grp", keep.by = FALSE))
#[[1]]
#   somestuff someotherstuff
#1:       sdr              Y
#2:     utyrd              V
#3:      ytrd              F
#4:        fc              W

#[[2]]
#   somestuff someotherstuff
#1:       09h              N
#2:       87h              H

#[[3]]
#   somestuff someotherstuff
#1:       0ij              K
#2:      5fdg              A
#3:        g7              C
#4:    h8o7hy              I
```

---

Or this can be done with `base R`

```
i1 <- is.na(dat$somestuff)
split(dat[!i1], cumsum(i1)[!i1])
```

Comment: Wow, appending a group assignment with releid() was exactly what I've been trying to do.  Not seen this before.  That is perfect.  Great answer and it's in the data.table.verse too. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Frank Thank you, that is more compact and I didn't know about the `keep.by` argument